# Servicestack getAsync explanation

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I'm quite new to webservices and rest, and I'm currently playing around with servicestack.

I have the following code, which works:

```
var response = client.Get<MeasurementResult>(SettingsManager.getMeasurementPath(1));
Measurement measurement = response.result;
```

I want to solve this asynchronously, but I don't really understand the documentation on this.
http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client

How can I achieve the above shown example wit getAsync instead of get? My main problem is the submission of the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the async / await modifiers on your code (and mark the containing method as async as well):

```
async Measurement GetMeasurement()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync<MeasurementResult>(SettingsManager.getMeasurementPath(1)));
    return response.Result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add a timeout directly to this?

Comment: This is just an asynchronous call, there's no concept of timeouts. It all depends on the library. If they expose a method which accepts a timeout you can, otherwise that'd be impossible and you'd have to create your own timeout mechanism.